# Get value from displayfor with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I want get the decimal value  of `@html.DisplayFor` with jQuery and pass with json.

I try with:

```
var debtor = $("#debtor").val();
```

but I gain `debtor` and not the decimal value.

```
<span class="debtorVal" style="color: red">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Debtor, new { id = "debtor" })
</span>
```

The `model => model.Debtor` is decimal number

Comment: show rendered html code

Comment: `DisplayFor()` just renders text. Its inside the `<span>` so just use `var debtor = $("#debtorVal").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple html tag:

```
<span class="debtorVal" style="color: red">
      <span id="debtor">@model.Debtor</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting value of `span`, `div`, `p` use `.text();` instead of `.val();`

```
var debtor = $(".debtorVal").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I gess you should change your markup to this:

```
<span id="debtor"  class="debtorVal" style="color: red">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Debtor)
</span>
```

Note that i place `id` attribute to `span` tag like @Stephen Muecke advice you.

And you can get value like this with jQuery now:

```
var debtor = $("#debtor").text();
```

And solution with pure js:

```
var debtor = document.getElementById("debtor").innerHTML;
```